# Unexpected Black View while using RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

### Problem

---

I've wrapped a `SurfaceView` and two `Button`s in a `RelativeLayout`.  But, unknown problem happened.

It creates a black view which is shown in the screenshot. And from the end the `SurfaceView` start or the `SurfaceView` stays at the back of the black view.

**Source**:(*surface_look.xml*)

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/mainSurface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:translationZ="15dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/surface_up"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/surface_down"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result**(*MainActivity*)
[image: Layout Runtime Screenshot]

**Update on Scott's comment**
[image: Screenshot after changing background]
When I change the `background` color of the `RelativeLayout` the black view changes to the color. That means it's the background of the `RelativeLayout`. Than there arise two questions.

- Why doesn't it fill the whole height?
- And why the `SurfaceView` starts from the end of the Layout it's
  wrapped in?

Comment: It's because the default color for the surface view is black color, to change the color use android:backgroundTint="@color/yourColor"

Comment: @deepakkumar The black view about I'm telling isn't `SurfaceView` because when I try to draw it draws at the gray color thing I've mentioned in the screenshot. It doesn't draw at the black view.

Comment: What happens if you set a background colour for the RelativeLayout, does that override the "black view" you're seeing or does it persist over the top of the RelativeLayout?

Comment: @ScottBarbour - Color changed read the update.

Comment: Well to me it looks like you've set up the attributes correctly to position your `SurfaceView` the way you want . My personal preference would be to use a `ConstraintLayout` as the root view as it's generally better at placing child views the way you want and it's really intuitive. I'd try changing to using that instead of your `RelativeLayout` and see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[As per our chat in the comments of your question]

Here's what your `surface_look.xml` layout file would look like if using a `ConstraintLayout` as your root view. Give it a try and see if it solves your positioning problem that you're facing when using a `RelativeLayout`.

NB You'll have to include the constraint layout dependency to use it in your code.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- let the constraints of the surface view determine it's width and height -->

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/mainSurface"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:translationZ="15dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/surface_up"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/surface_down"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: In Fact, I don't want to use any dependency because I'm using AIDE. It takes storage to save dependency. But, thanks and I'll try another layout except `RelativeLayout` or other way. +1